# I need help identifying what this might be

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount, automotive

This is my DRL module for a 1998 Toyota corolla. Not exactly an easy find to replace. This three pin SMD is on the board. I initially thought it might have been a transistor, but PCB is marked as ZD, which further confuses me. I have never heard of a Zener diode having three pins. But this is, (I'm assuming) a switching path, as my lights do not technically turn OFF until I unplug the DRL module, which gets pretty annoying after a year of doing so. There are no circuit diagrams online and the only info I can provide is that the other parts listed as ZD have codes of 471, 562, and 101 on them. This one is on the PCB in a row of two others, which are marked '471' which leads me to believe this could be the code for it. But essentially, the car had a bad ground and blew this diode out, and I need to fix it. Any advice? (Unfortunately, no picture can be provided as it isn't a high enough quality to be legible under 2 MB) (also the diode is definitely burnt on one end. No other part has failure, all tests as normal.)

Comment: Make a picture, use the macro-modus and additional light. Right now I can not help you,

Comment: Could be a zener diode array. (2 zener diodes with one terminal shared between them). Digikey lists over a thousand such arrays: https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/filter/diodes/zener/zener-diode-arrays/295?s=N4IgjCBcoEwAwHYqgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2iACxwwCsSxN9AbCALrEAOALlCAGUeAJwCWAOwDmIAL7EwATgAcC5CDSQseIqQog4HOSAC0q6OqgiArjrKRKEdjOdA

Comment: Also could be a zener diode with an unused pin, again pretty common in a variety of configurations.

Comment: put an ignition controlled relay in the supply to the lights - they will be off until ignition comes on.

Comment: _"high enough quality to be legible under 2mb"_ Crop and decrease quality/increase compression.

Answer (score 1):

The markings and packaging you describe match with a [Philips PZM4.7NB1](https://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/nxp_pzm_n_series.pdf) diode.

[image]

Searching for images of the part, I found this forum thread which might be relevant to your problem: [Transistor identification? Pictures included, help?](https://www.edaboard.com/threads/transistor-identification-pictures-included-help.120449/)